# How many device tokens total can I push to in UrbanAirship for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

```
notification = {
  :schedule_for => [1.hour.from_now],
  :device_tokens => ['DEVICE-TOKEN-ONE', 'DEVICE-TOKEN-TWO'],
  :aps => {:alert => 'You have a new message!', :badge => 1}
}
```

For example :device_tokens one, two, three. Can I send in a million? What is the limit?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the HTTP request timing out. Generally Urban Airship recommends around 3,000 device ids, but again, be sure to test the timeouts yourself as that will vary.